# Filling gridview with alphabets

Tags: android, gridview

I am a beginner. I am making an education app which will read out the alphabet name when someone touch them.

For that I want to fill the gridview with alphabets. Can you tell me how to do this. Which adapter to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use an ArrayAdapter and add the alphabet in a List or String[] to it.

An example [how to use the GridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) can be found here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and fill it with either String or Character to represent each letter.